# PHP Mustache. Implicit iterator: How to get key of current value(numeric php array)

Tags: mustache, mustache.php

If I have php array like this:

```
 $a = array (
    99 => 'Something1',
    184 => 'Something2',
 );
```

And keys present important information - It can be some constant values, ids e.t.c

Then how can I get key of current element from templete.
For example:

```
{{#data}}

{.} - it is current value, but I need key also.

{{/data}}
```

In our system too much these kind of arrays and it is uncomfortably re-parse them before. What's better solution for this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to iterate over an associative array in Mustache, because Mustache sees it as a "hash" rather than an iterable list. And even if you could iterate over the list, you would not be able to access the keys.

In order to do this, you must prepare your data. You could do it with a foreach loop before you pass the data into Mustache, or you could do it by wrapping your array in a "Presenter". Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
<?php

class IteratorPresenter implements IteratorAggregate
{
    private $values;

    public function __construct($values)
    {
        if (!is_array($values) && !$values instanceof Traversable) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('IteratorPresenter requires an array or Traversable object');
        }

        $this->values = $values;
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        $values = array();
        foreach ($this->values as $key => $val) {
            $values[$key] = array(
                'key'   => $key,
                'value' => $val,
                'first' => false,
                'last'  => false,
            );
        }

        $keys = array_keys($values);

        if (!empty($keys)) {
            $values[reset($keys)]['first'] = true;
            $values[end($keys)]['last']    = true;
        }

        return new ArrayIterator($values);
    }
}
```

Then simply wrap your array in the Presenter:

```
$view['data'] = new IteratorPresenter($view['data']);
```

You now have access to the keys and values while iterating over your data:

```
{{# data }}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{{/ data }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the class. I tested it and use it now in a stable live environment. Works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I love mustache. While learning I found this question and felt it needed an appropriate answer.

```
$this->keyValueArray = Array(
    "key1" => "val1",
    "key2" => "val2",
    "key3" => "val3"
);

$tempArray = array();
foreach($this->keyValueArray as $key=>$val){
    $tempArray[] = Array("keyName" => $key, "valName" => $val);
}

$this->mustacheReadyData = ArrayIterator($tempArray);
```

Then you can use it in your template like so:

```
{{#mustacheReadyData}}
    Key: {{keyName}} Value: {{valName}}
{{/mustacheReadyData}}
```

This can be expanded much further than Key/Val by adding more values in the foreach loop.