# Consuming complex array with keys in php mustache

Tags: php, arrayiterator, mustache.php

I have following structure of array `arr`

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [width] => 600 
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [bgColor] => 'red' 
                        )



                ) 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [width] => 400 
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [bgColor] => 'blue' 
                        )



                ) 
        )

)
```

Currently I am passing data as,

```
$tpl->render(array( 
   'arr'   => new ArrayIterator($arr)                       
));
```

In in mustache template, I am consuming it like,

```
{{#arr}}  
  {{width}}
{{/arr}}
```

It gives me `width` correctly. But now I want the `keys` of that array ( `1` for first and `3` for second one) and also the total no of elements in `pages` key.

How can I do this mustache ?

Comment: Replace your `ArrayIterator` with the Presenter class in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15619309/213448

Comment: @bobthecow, I have never worked with `ArrayIterator` before. Can you clarify how's that gonna help ? Also, I am not exactly sure where to put this classes ? I am particularly working in wp. Will that class help me other than giving structure ?

Comment: The `IteratorPresenter` is a Presenter (or ViewModel) that provides an implicit `key`, `value`, `first` and `last` property for each element in your original array. It's a generic Presenter, meant for use with any array or iterable, but you could also make a Presenter for just your data set if you have more specific needs. See Wikipedia for more on Presenters — http://hile.mn/12lVbky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I understand that mustache cannot keep track of `index` of array and it needs everything in `hash`.

So, I am using following technique, it works but little bit ugly.

```
function prepareForMustache ($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $k => &$v) {
        $v['key']  = $k;
        $v['pagesCount'] = count($v['pages']);
    } 
}


$arr = prepareForMustache($arr);

$tpl->render(array( 
   'arr'   => new ArrayIterator($arr)                       
));
```

And consuming in mustache template as,

```
{{#arr}}  
  {{width}}
  {{key}}
  {{pagesCount}}
{{/arr}}
```